# Flutter Camera - Is it possible to take a photo while app is running on background?

Tags: flutter, background, camera

I want to make an app that take a photo in specific time, 3:00PM everyday, for example.

My design of the app is

Run my app on background -> get current time -> take a picture from camera if current time == desired time

I found the library named `flutter_background_video_recorder` but it says it is not available for iOS.

Is there any library to accomplish this object ? Any advice is very graceful .

Comment: No, not any any modern consumer operating system. That would be a huge privacy concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,iOS has strict permission limit.
Even Android devices may end up in the background

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible, even if it did, apple will reject your app submission.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).